# Rsyslog filter for logging router events (syslog server)

Tags: 12.04, server, router, rsyslog

I am trying to configure rsyslog (Ubuntu 12.04 Server) to log events from a router. I found this old [ubuntu forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1349364) which got me most of the way there.

So far I am able to get the events logged from the router. However since I don't them logged in `/var/log/syslog` I am trying to set up a working filter in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to put the logged events in `/var/log/linksys.log`.  This is where I am having trouble.

- First I tried filtering by the router ip address like this:

  ```
  :fromhost-ip, isequal, "192.168.2.1" /var/log/linksys.log
  & ~
  ```

  This successfully redirects the logs as I wanted, the only problem is now I am not getting any SSHD logs in auth.log.  Needless to say this is not acceptable.
- Next I tried filtering by the router name which appears in every event log:

  ```
  :msg,contains, "RV042" /var/log/linksys.log
  & ~
  ```

  Although this neither logs or blocks anything.

So I am stumped. I have no idea why SSHD is getting filtered with the `:fromhost-ip` filter.  SSHD is local on the machine with rsyslog (192.168.2.2).  I am thoroughly frustrated by this, any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!  These links helped:

http://www.rsyslog.com/tag/udp/

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/multi_ruleset.html

## Here's what I did:

Opened up `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` and at the top of the file, before other all of the default filters, I added:

```
# process remote messages
# define new ruleset and add rules to it:
$RuleSet remote
*.*           /var/log/linksys.log
# only messages not from 192.168.2.1 make it past this point

# bind ruleset to UDP listener
$InputUDPServerBindRuleset remote
# and activate it:
$UDPServerRun 514

# switch back to the default ruleset:
$RuleSet RSYSLOG_DefaultRuleset
```

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/rsyslog.conf` is not the right file to be editing. You really want to be setting up a separate `.conf` file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.d/20-router.conf
```

Then add the required configuration:

```
:fromhost-ip, isequal, "192.168.2.1" /var/log/linksys.log
& ~
```

This shouldn't confuse any other log entries. Just tried this myself and it works fine.

Thanks to http://nickhumphreyit.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-setup-syslog-server-on-ubuntu.html for giving me the answer, after giving up on the documentation.

You may want to add a `logrotate` file to `/etc/logrotate.d/linksys` too:

```
/var/log/linksys.log {
       daily
       rotate 7
       delaycompress
       compress
       notifempty
       missingok
}
```